# Unable to remove table row

Tags: jquery, knockout.js

I am using this code to add a new row in my table:

```
 var CA = function() {
                            this.CAName = null;
                            this.CAAdress = null;
                            this.CAIdNum = null;
                            this.CAContact = null;
                            this.CAName = null;
                            this.CANote = null;
                            this.CAType = null;
                        };

                        newCreditRows = function () {
                            this.creditRows.push(new CA());
                        };
```

[Full js fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/9cAMz/)

The problem I have is that I can not remove the new row(added by the `newCreditRows` function). I have tried to do it in few different ways like:
`this.creditRows.remove(CA);`
 but without luck. I need to remove it, because null values are inserted in my observable array and it is creating huge problems when I'm looping trough the records. I'm sure that I'm missing something really small, but as a junior developer, I'm not able to fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9cAMz/3/)

```
var vm = {
    newCreditRows : function () {

        this.creditRows.push(new CA());
    },
    remove :  function(ca){
        vm.creditRows.remove(ca);
   },
    creditRows : ko.observableArray()
};
```

I hope it helps.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to delete only the last inserted this code does the job. I store the newly created row in a temp var named `nova`. When you click the button `remove` I remove the nova row form the array:

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9cAMz/1/

Answer (score 1):

You can add remove function to your object:

```
removeCreditRow : function (parent){
    parent.creditRows.remove(this);
}
```

And use it as follow:

```
    <td><a href="#" data-bind="click: $parent.removeCreditRow.bind($data, $parent)">Remove</a> </td>
```

Here is working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9cAMz/2/